# Why is my batch file showing all variables

Tags: batch-file

I am coding a text-based batch rpg, but the code reads all variables formatted as :VARIABLE
echo
set
if
etc.

as if it was a sequence of code.

CODE:

```
:start
@echo off
set /p name=Welcome to the game, what is your name?:
if %name%==ChrisPBacon goto crispy
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
goto selectclass


:WARRIORSELECT1
cls
set /p question1=Your class is Warrior, is this correct Y/N?:
if %question1%==Y cls goto skillselect1
if %question1%==N cls goto selectclass

:PALADINSELECT1
cls
set /p question1=Your class is Paladin, is this correct Y/N?:
if %question1%==Y cls goto skillselect1
if %question1%==N cls goto selectclass

:MAGESELECT1
cls
set /p question1=Your class is Mage, is this correct Y/N?:
if %question1%==Y cls goto skillselect1
if %question1%==N cls goto selectclass

:CLERICSELECT1
cls
set /p question1=Your class is Cleric, is this correct Y/N?:
if %question1%==Y cls goto clerichealer
if %question1%==N cls goto selectclass


:selectclass
echo Welcome to the game, %name%!
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
echo Warrior
echo Paladin
echo Mage
echo Cleric
set /p CLASS=What class would you like to be?:
if %CLASS%==Warrior goto WARRIORSELECT1
if %CLASS%==Paladin goto PALADINSELECT1
if %CLASS%==Mage goto MAGESELECT1
if %CLASS%==Cleric goto CLERICSELECT1


:clerichealer
set /p surecleric=Are you sure you wish to be the Cleric? This class does 0 
damage and can only heal Y/N!:
if %surecleric%==Y cls goto skillselect1
if %surecleric%==N cls goto selectclass

:skillselect1
echo Welcome to the skill selection menu, %Name% the %CLASS% From here you 
can select your initial skills, with 10 points to spend at first and more 
can be gained by levelling up!
echo Weight (W)
echo Attack Damage (AD)
echo Magic Damage (MD)
echo Healing Effectiveness (HE)
set /p point1 What attribute do you wish to level up with your 1st point?
if point1==W echo Increased weight by +10!
if point1==AD echo Increased Attack Damage by +20!
if point1==MD echo Increased Magic Damage by +15!
if point1==HE echo Increased Healing Effectiveness by +10 Health!














:crispy
echo Welcome Admin!
echo 
echo 1) Force Delete current save
echo 2) Implement Preset save
set /p bacon=What do you wish to do?
```

In particular, when any class but Cleric is selected, it loops through all classes asking if this is your selected class. When Cleric is selected, it loops back to Welcome to the game, %name% etc.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in this snippet.

```
:CLERICSELECT1
cls
set /p question1=Your class is Cleric, is this correct Y/N?:
if %question1%==Y cls goto clerichealer
if %question1%==N cls goto selectclass


:selectclass
```

- If your selection is not `Y` or `N`, it will automatically go on, and reach `:selectclass`. This problem occurs throughout the entire script, so fix them first.
- Another thing that most new batch scripts make is the multicommand in one `if` statement. You could use

`if "a"=="b" cls && goto blah`

or

```
if "a"=="b" (
    cls
    goto blah
)
```

- Notice the quotes `"` I've added, as quotes will help deal with variables with spaces.
- Optionally, you can add the `/i` flag to `if`, which means case-insensitive search.
- When we want to `echo` a blank line, we don't only use `echo`, instead, we use  `echo(`, though there are some less safer methods.
- Some variables are not wrapped in % signs.
- Multi-line echo requires multi `echo`s unless you want `for` loops
- There was one missing equal sign in one of the `set /p` statement
- Storing passwords directly in a batch file isn't safe, **even after making it a `.exe` file**, as most `bat to exe converter` does make a temporary `bat` file in the temp directory, which can be easily accessed by malicious users.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that makes it loop when you select cleric is that it just goes on, even when you enter "n" (instead of "N"), as SteveFest said.

But there are many issues with your code:

- It doesn't account for incorrect or empty input
- The if comparison is case-sensitive
- no quotes for the if comparison
- It's obvious it's going to get much worse with time if you keep using too many goto statements